# iTunes doesn't open, no error messages or anything, not even when executed through terminal

Tags: macos, itunes

I just updated to iTunes 12, and I when I open it, nothing happens. The icon on the Dock doesn't even bounce. When I start it in the Terminal, nothing happens either, no messages. When I open it with `sudo`, the application does show up in the dock with a dot, but no messages or UI.

I don't think it has anything to do with my user profile since it does not work in `sudo` either, it does come closer to work though, but it's a very very small difference. I have rebooted the computer, obviously.

I also tried reinstalling it, it's been stuck on "moving files to their right places" with 1 minute left for *7* hours.

Comment: Did you start the app bundle or the executable in there? If the app, then execute the executable in `appname.app/Contents/MacOs`

Comment: @TheBro21 the executable.

Comment: Could there be a log in the **Console.app** with iTunes, the last time it did work? It should be under *Diagnostic and Usage Info**, in User Diag reports. Also look in **Files > /Library/logs > Crash Reporter** and **Diag reports**

Answer (score 1):

"1 minute left" is the sign for "I'm doing your user stuff right now, I have no clue when it will finish, 'cos that depends on how much stuff you've got" … but if you've force-quit it, you broke it & will have to start over.

There is similar confusion at OS updates, the "doing your user stuff" part apparently cannot be predicted anywhere near as well as the initial processing/update, so you get a "1 minute" that can take hours. Patience is a virtue; in fact patience should be directly proportional to the time since your last solid backup.

I'd clear the saved state for starters & see how that goes …
`~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.iTunes.savedState`

Comment: Clearing the saved state also helps if iTunes stubbornly refuses to open *any* window on startup.

Comment: Clearing saved state is my favourite 'first fix' attempt for anything that's being a bit awkward - because it loses little yet potentially gains much :)

Answer (score -1):

Try opening in Safe Mode.

Command + Option keys when launching iTunes